# Find the Inverse of this function: $y= \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$y= \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$

I multiplied both sides by the denominator. However, I am stuck at that point. Help?

Answer (score 6):

$$
y(1+\sqrt{x}) = 1-\sqrt{x} \implies (1+y)\sqrt{x} = 1-y\implies \sqrt{x} = \frac{1-y}{1+y}
$$
so 
$$
x = \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 3):

The square root might be a little daunting, so let's get rid of it... $u = \sqrt{x}$:

$$\begin{split}
y &= \frac{1-u}{1+u} \\
y(1+u) &= 1-u \\
(y+1)u &= 1 - y \\
u &= \frac{1-y}{1+y} \\
x &= \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2
\end{split}$$

Comment: So how did you get rid of the square root after u substitution? Did you take the derivative of the square root?

Comment: @SkakaZulu $x = u^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is always useful to recall that $f(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is an involutive map, i.e. $f(f(z))=z$.

That gives that the inverse of your function is just $\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$f(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}.$$ Put $$g(x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x}\quad \text{and} \quad h = \sqrt{x},$$ so that $f = g \circ h$. This gives $f^{-1} = h^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$. But: $$g(x) = \frac{-x+1}{x+1} \implies g^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-1}{-x-1} = \frac{-x+1}{x+1}.$$Hence: $$f^{-1}(x) = \left(\frac{-x+1}{x+1}\right)^2$$

Remark: I'm not worrying too much about domains and such, since this seems to be a more manipulative exercise. To get quickly the inverse of functions of the $(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ like, think of [Möbius Transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Answer (score 1):

Without stating the domains explicitly the answer is incomplete. So, the inverse of the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}, \qquad x \in [0,+\infty) 
$$ 
is the function 
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2, \qquad x \in (-1,1]. 
$$
Let us promote rigor here.

[image]